# Add a value to the i variable of Angular's ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I want to create two rows of five inputs using ngFor. I want to store the inputs in an array so I figured I would use the index in the ngModel. However, when I try to add a value for the second row to the `let i = index`, I get Template parse errors.

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let row of [0,5]">
    <div class="col-md-5ths" *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4]; let i = index + row">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="input[i]">
      {{input[i]}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried some variations with a ternary operator and ngForOf, but to no success. It seems Angular is a lot stricter than AngularJS in this regard.

[Plunker here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/6o4Al1AlFUvG999w8HZ5?p=preview)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved so:

```
 <div class="col-md-5ths" *ngFor="let number of [0,1,2,3,4]; let i = index">
      <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="input[i+row]">
      {{input[i+row]}}
 </div>
```